# Need assistance on make file in c

Tags: c

I have a quick question on make files in c. Is it possible to have more than one target when generating a make file? I am in the process of generating code, and I just wanted to know is it possible. Thanks all!

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question. Could you illustrate it with an example?

Comment: Do you mean more than one target **built** that are independent of each other? Like `make target1 target2` ?

Comment: Yes...that's precisely what I mean

Comment: @Mat Sorry Mat.I was referring to make files. For example, when you are in the process of compiling source code, can you have more than one target defined through the use of a make file.

Comment: You can define as many targets as you like. In some cases it make a lot of sense - `make clean`, `make install`, ... Target for each sourcecode file are also possible, this is what most texts about getting startet show you - but it is rarely what you want.

Comment: What are "make files in C"?

Comment: The file that allows you specify, for example, the target source file. I dont know if thats the best explanation though lol..

Comment: Makefiles are language-agnostic. They are just a recipe of things that can get done (targets) and their dependencies used by the program `make`. Thus you can simply specify several targets.

Answer (score 3):

An introduction to makefiles [here](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/)
In the example in that page:

```
all: hello

hello: main.o factorial.o hello.o
    g++ main.o factorial.o hello.o -o hello

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

factorial.o: factorial.cpp
    g++ -c factorial.cpp

hello.o: hello.cpp
    g++ -c hello.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *o hello
```

All, hello, clean are all different targets, so you can type `make all`, `make clean` and so on.

Comment: `make clean all` is a handy command as well.